# How to solve this error (Nest & Prisma): ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'organ')

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, nest, prisma

I'm developing an API using Nestjs and Prisma, the problem occurs when I try to insert information in the Database (Postgres), I get this error, saying that it cannot read the "organ" property which is the table in which I intend to insert the information.

The error is occurring in the repository in the create method:
`

```
import { Organ } from '@prisma/client';
import { CreateOrganDto } from '../../../../../modules/organs/dto/create-organ.dto';
import { IOrganRepository } from '../../../../../modules/organs/repositories/IOrganRepository';
import { PrismaService } from '../../../../../shared/infra/db/prisma.service';

export class OrganRepository implements IOrganRepository {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {} 

  async create({ name }: CreateOrganDto): Promise<Organ> {
    const organ = await this.prisma.organ.create({
      data: {
        name
      },
    });

    return organ;
  }

  async findByName(name: string): Promise<Organ | null> {
    const organ = await this.prisma.organ.findUnique({
      where: {
        name,
      },
    });

    return organ;
  }
}
```

`

a const organ dev

```
this.prisma.organ.create method is returning an Organ, never type when it should just return Organ
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the PrismaClient is not in sync with Prisma Schema.
You would need to invoke `npx prisma generate` in order to regenerate the PrismaClient - [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#generate).

Also, I would recommend checking that all models defined in schema file has been created in the database, you can either use `npx prisma migrate dev` or `npx prisma db push` to create the corresponding tables - [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate).